# Testing react components with enzyme - select tag not updating after first simulation of 'change' event

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a react component with three select tags. I want to check if the `onChange` methods are being called (which I do using `sinon.spy`). I want to try out all combinations of all values of the three select tags. The code is as shown:

```
describe("Testing Selects", () => {
    let spy1 = sinon.spy(Filter.prototype, "onSelect1Changed");
    let spy2 = sinon.spy(Filter.prototype, "onSelect2Changed");
    let spy3 = sinon.spy(Filter.prototype, "onSelect3Changed");
    let wrapper = mount(<Filter/>);

    let values1 = wrapper.find("#select1").children().map(node => node.prop("value"));
    let values2 = wrapper.find("#select2").children().map(node => node.prop("value"));
    let values3 = wrapper.find("#select3").children().map(node => node.prop("value"));

    it("Testing different combinations of filters", () => {
        for(let i=0; i<values1.length; i++) {
            wrapper.update();
            wrapper.find("#select1").simulate("change", {target: {value: values1[i]}});
            expect(spySelect1Changed.called).toEqual(true);
            console.log("Select 1", values1[i]);
            for(let j=0; j<values2.length; j++) {
                wrapper.find("#select2").simulate("change", {target: {value: values2[j]}});
                expect(spySelect2Changed.called).toEqual(true);
                console.log("Select 2", values2[j]);
                for(let k=0; k<values3.length; k++) {
                    wrapper.find("#select3").simulate("change", {target: {value: values3[k]}});
                    expect(spySelect3Changed.called).toEqual(true);
                    console.log("Select 3", values3[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It gives a warning saying, `Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().`. Following is the output:

```
Select 1 -1
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 2 Last2Hours
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 2 Last2Hours
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 2 Last2Hours
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 2 Last2Hours
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 2 Last2Hours
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
Warning: setState(...): You passed an undefined or null state object; instead, use forceUpdate().
Select 3 Now
```

As can be seen, the value of the select tags are not changing after the first time. How can we simlulate the `change` event multiple times?

Comment: it looks like your console.log statements are copy-pasted wrongly. In inner loop, it should be `values2[j]` and in innermost loop, it should be `values3[k]` instead of `values2[i]` and `values3[i]`

Comment: The question title does not reflect the question content. Is it possible to edit the title / content to make it more accurate? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out! I made a mistake while copying.